# fastlane send existing build to tesflight external users

Tags: testflight, fastlane

We have a lane that submits to the appstore, which handles uploading to the appstore. I'd like to take those *already* uploaded builds and submit them for external review.

From what I can tell, both the appstore and tesflight actions are expecting an actual ipa to be available to upload. What I'd like to do is to run a lane that will take an already processed build and submit it for external testing with tesflight.

Essentially, I'd like to periodically run a lane that checks if the latest build has been submitted for external testing, and if it hasn't I want to submit it.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no action that does this automatically. However if you look at [the relevant source code for `pilot`](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/pilot/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb) you can see that it uses `Spaceship` to connect to App Store Connect and wait for a build that matches the one just upload. Once it finds it, it submits it for external review if that option is on.

You can use similar code to achieve this, either in your Fastfile or in a new fastlane plug-in.